# no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::_Setfill<const char*>')

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw-w64, iomanip

I just started learning cpp in my school. I was trying to do this thing:

Please follow the format of the output example to output the design and color of NxN twill floor tiles.

Note: The design and color of the twill floor tiles are like this. Firstly, each grid on the diagonal line from the upper left to the lower right is an '@' symbol, and the diagonal line is shifted to the left and right by three grids, that is, the interval is two The pattern on the line after the grid is also '@', and then continue to repeat on both sides until it exceeds the range of the floor tiles. Where there is no '@' pattern, it is represented by a '-' symbol.

```
EXAMPLE =
INPUT
10

OUTPUT
@--@--@--
-@--@--@-
--@--@--@
@--@--@--
-@--@--@-
--@--@--@
@--@--@--
-@--@--@-
--@--@--@
```

I tried to use setw and setfill, heres my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){;
    int a,i,n;
    cin >> a;
    n=a;

    for(i=1;i<=a;i++){
        cout<<setw(a);
        if(n==1||(n-1)%3==0){
            cout<<setfill("@--")<<"@";
            cout<<endl;
        }
        if(n==2||(n-2)%3==0){
            cout<<setfill("-@-")<<"-";
            cout<<endl;
        }
        if(n==3||(n-3)%3==0){
            cout<<"--";
            cout<<setfill("--@")<<"--";
            cout<<endl;
        }
        n=n-1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

What i tried to do was trying to input from the back of the line, since from what i know, setw and setfill fill from the back of the input line.

There were 3 scenarios i set, starting with '@','-',or'--'. And after the scenario was met, i tried to fill the remaining input width with '@--','-@-',or'--@'.

But, when i tried to compile the file, the compiler says:

```
no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::_Setfill<const char*>')
```

and i have no idea what was the error and how to solve it.

What's the error I ecountered, and how to solve it? Also if possible, is there another optimal way to write the code?

Thank you so much.

**Edit:**
i rewrote the code, this time using more arrays, if and for loops. It finally worked. Thank you for the insights!

here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    char one[a];
    char two[a];
    char three[a];

    int eFst,eScd,eTrd;
    //1,4,7... line elements
    for(eFst=0;eFst<a;eFst++){
        if((eFst-1)%3==0){
            one[eFst]='-';
            }
        if((eFst-2)%3==0){
            one[eFst]='-';
            }
        if((eFst-3)%3==0){
            one[eFst]='@';
            }
    }
    //2,5,8... line elements
    for(eScd=0;eScd<a;eScd++){
        if((eScd-1)%3==0){
            two[eScd]='@';
            }
        if((eScd-2)%3==0){
            two[eScd]='-';
            }
        if((eScd-3)%3==0){
            two[eScd]='-';
            }
    }
    //3,6,9... line elements
    for(eTrd=0;eTrd<a;eTrd++){
        if((eTrd-1)%3==0){
            three[eTrd]='-';
            }
        if((eTrd-2)%3==0){
            three[eTrd]='@';
            }
        if((eTrd-3)%3==0){
            three[eTrd]='-';
            }
    }
    
    int i,rFst,rScd,rTrd;       
//how many rows
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        //1,4,7 line and so on
        if((i-3)%3==0){
            for(rFst=0;rFst<a;rFst++){
                cout<<one[rFst];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        //2,5,8 line and so on
        if((i-1)%3==0){
            for(rScd=0;rScd<a;rScd++){
                cout<<two[rScd];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        //3,6,9 line and so on
        if((i-2)%3==0){
            for(rTrd=0;rTrd<a;rTrd++){
                cout<<three[rTrd];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

If there are ways to optimise my code, please kindly let me know, thanks!

Comment: [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) takes a character, not a string

Comment: That's not how [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) works. It takes single character that is used to fill if `std::setw` is set and the element to print is shorter than value passed to `setw`.

Comment: As a matter of style, that loop is always written `for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) ...`. When you start using arrays you'll see the importance of starting at 0 rather than 1. That's not an issue in the code here; the loop runs the right number of times.

Comment: what is the best way to solve this problem? for loop? while? arrays?

Comment: I think simplest is a for loop on line with inside a for loop on column. It's easier if line and column start to 0. Then we print a `@`or a '-'. The only challenge is to find the test to decide between them. See the picture, if column==line a `@` is drawn. Find all cases for the `@` is a simple expression using the modulo 3.

Comment: it's kinda puzzling to find the exact parameter which fulfills the function condition. It took me several guess-and-checks to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody knows all C++ by heart. You need to get accustomed to some reference where you can look stuff up. I recommend cppreference.com.

[std::setfill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) is

> ```
> template< class CharT >
> /*unspecified*/ setfill( CharT c );
> ```

It is a function template with unspecified return type. This may sound a little odd, but most iomanipulators are functions. `CharT` denotes the character type. Strings and streams and most related stuff is parametrized on the character type. When you use `std::cout` of type `std::ostream` that is actually `std::basic_ostream<char>` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream). Hence, here you want to use `std::setfill<char>`. The template parameter can be deduced so you only need to supply a parameter:

```
 std::cout << std::setfill('.');
```

The error message is rather intersting...

```
no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::_Setfill<const char*>')
```

`std::_Setfill<const char*>` is the unspecified return type from above. In a different standard library implementation it could be a totally different type. Its just something that you can pipe to eg `std::cout` to get the desired effect. There is `const char*` because the character array `"@--"`, a `const char[4]`, has decayed to a pointer.

TL;DR: `std::setfill` does not works with strings as argument.

Comment: Thank you. In other words, setfill cant have strings as inputs.